# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11232, 5616]

Tags: machine-learning, python

[image]

I don't know what is the reason for the error please guide me and help me out. I am at a learning stage.

Comment: If you are only splitting the training labels (since you’re throwing away the train_w2v split), you don’t need to provide train_w2v in the call. So you could remove the _, _,  and remove train_w2v.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the train and train_w2v dataframes have s variable number of rows. You will  have to make their shapes consistent before doing a train-test-split